# VueJS and Axios: Component loading state is not being updated when I Abort Axios network request?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, http, axios, vuex

I have a dashboard dates-filters dropdown, each time the dropdown value get changed by the user I send multiple network requests using `Axios`.

To prevent Sub-sequent API calls when the user changes the date-filters quickly I abort all previous requests using JS [AbortController](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/AbortController) if they are still pending state.

I use custom loading VueJS state's on my component to show loading screens and based on request states Ex below:

Vue Html template

```
      <template>
        <div v-if="loadingSpendingCard">
          Loading...
        </div>

        <SpendingCard v-else/>
      </template>
```

Vue Methods

```
{
...,
methods: {
  fetchData(){
      this.$store.dispatch("CANCEL_PENDING_REQUESTS");

      this.loadingSpendingCard = true;
       axiosApiClient.get("/user-spending");
        .then((response) => {
          console.log(response)
        })
        .catch((error) => {
          console.log(error);
        })
        .finally(() => {
          this.loadingSpendingCard = false;
        });
 }
}
```

Using `Axios` request interceptors I add a new AbortController to each request and handle their state from the `VueX` for later cancellation of the request. To cancel this requests I use `VueX` actions that is called in the beginig of `fetchData()` using this guide [here](https://blog.andrewjamesbibby.com/2019/08/01/cancel-all-pending-axios-requests-in-vue-spa-on-router-change/)

`fetchData()` is being called each time the date-filters value changes. Which means previous requests are being called sucessfully and new request's are being sent.

The Problem: Each time I abort the requests the `loadingSpendingCard` is set to `false` and the new request i being sent, but `loadingSpendingCard` is stuck on `false` it does not update the value to `true`.

I am expecting for the `loadingSpendingCard` state to be assigned to `true` on each new request after aborting.

I tried using keeping the state to `true` and not changing it if the `error === "canceled"` , which works but i have over more than 20 requests and why my above solution does not work.

```
  fetchData(){
      this.$store.dispatch("CANCEL_PENDING_REQUESTS");

      this.loadingSpendingCard = true;
       axiosApiClient.get("/user-spending");
        .then((response) => {
          console.log(response)
        })
        .catch((error) => {

         if(error === "canceled"){
          console.log("Canceled request")
         }else{
          this.loadingSpendingCard = false;
          console.log(error);
          }

        })
 }
```

Why the `loadingSpendingCard` state does not update to `true`?

Comment: The question lacks https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve , that you don't strictly chain promises like $store.dispatch("CANCEL_PENDING_REQUESTS") suggests that there may be race conditions. Any way, if there are multiple simultaneous requests, it's correct to use request counter instead of boolean state. `error === "canceled"` - it's unknown if it's so, usually an error is not a string, it would be AbortError in case of AbortController

Answer (score 0):

sometimes 'this' inside axios not working
so
define in start of your function

```
var self = this
```

then use this

```
          self.loadingSpendingCard = false;
```

like this

```
fetchData(){
  var self = this
  this.$store.dispatch("CANCEL_PENDING_REQUESTS");

  this.loadingSpendingCard = true;
   axiosApiClient.get("/user-spending");
    .then((response) => {
      console.log(response)
    })
    .catch((error) => {

     if(error === "canceled"){
      console.log("Canceled request")
     }else{
      self.loadingSpendingCard = false;
      console.log(error);
      }

    })
```

}